# No such file or directory in Git loading python file

Tags: python, git, git-bash

I run my file which in Desktop, and give this error. What am I missing?
Note: python version 3.5.3

```
C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/python3.exe: error while loading shared libraries: python34.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: this DLL should be in `C:\Windows\System32\python34.dll`. Is it there? "portable" install of python 3 doesn't seem to work: the DLL needs to be registered.

Comment: Apparently, it can't find `python34.dll`. Make sure it's in the C:/Program Files/Git/usr/include/python34.dll or somewhere else if you had python3.4 installed and the path is in the system include path.

Comment: another workaround: install the standard version of python 3.4.

Comment: But, currently i'm using python 3.5.3

Answer (score 0):

python34.dll seems to be missing. 
Make sure that you have it in your fold

Comment: Not its giving me
    `Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'`

Comment: My python file works well in python shell, but not in Git.

Comment: I don't know how to run your script using Git. 
However, the error says: No module named: 'encodings'.
Are you sure that the idle and git are running the same python instance?

Comment: i just load the pytho.py file using git bash.
What do you mean "idle and git are running the same python instance"? Can you elaborate?